# flycheck-gcc-include-path in .dir-locals.el

Tags: flycheck, directory-local-variables

In my `.dir-locals.el` I have:

```el
(cpp-mode . (setq flycheck-gcc-include-path '("/home/<user>/<project>/include")))
```

This doesnt seem to set `flycheck-gcc-include-path`, any ideas why?

Also is there a list option for `flycheck-gcc-include-path` so I can specify more than one include directory?

Edit: Heres my flycheck stuff in my `init.el`:

```el
;; syntax checker flycheck
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
; error showing up console
(with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
  (flycheck-pos-tip-mode))
;(setq flycheck-gcc-include-path '("/home/<user>/<project>"))
(setq flycheck-disabled-checkers '(c/c++-clang))
(setq flycheck-enabled-checkers '(c/c++-gcc))
```

If I uncomment the line for `flycheck-gcc-include-path` it works. I want this on a project basis so I am trying to set it in `.dir-locals.el`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a few potential issues:

1. I am not familiar with a `cpp-mode`; I assume you mean `c++-mode`.
2. The contents of a `dir-locals-file` should form an alist, i.e. `((mode . vars))` instead of `(mode . vars)`.
3. The `cdr` of each such mode-vars pair, i.e. the mode-specific settings, should also form an alist: `((mode . ((var . val))))` instead of `((mode . (var . val)))`.
4. Each variable-value pair results in the `cdr` (value) being assigned to the `car` (variable); the form is not evaluated as is. The `cdr` is only evaluated when the `car` comprises the special symbol `eval`.

So, your `dir-locals-file` should probably read:

```el
((c++-mode . ((flycheck-gcc-include-path . ("/home/<user>/<project>/include")))))
```

See the following info manual nodes for more information:

- [(emacs) Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html)
- [(elisp) Directory Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Local-Variables.html)

> Also is there a list option for flycheck-gcc-include-path so I can specify more than one include directory?

As far as I can tell from the variable's documentation (`C-h v flycheck-gcc-include-path RET`) it is supposed to be a list of directory paths. If this does not work you should consider reporting it as a bug.

Comment: Your solution worked thank you, I actually had c++-mode in my .dir i probably changed it at some point.Your point #3 did the trick. The mode and variable were supposed to form an alist!

 I have a question that the wiki seems to neglect.

What are the `.` for ?

Comment: The dots are due to the standard dotted pair notation for cons cells. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cons-Cell-Type.html#Cons-Cell-Type) and its subnode "Dotted Pair Notation" for more information.

Comment: @sp00kyb00g13 See also [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/List-Processing.html#List-Processing) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/car-cdr-_0026-cons.html#car-cdr-_0026-cons) from the Intro to Elisp manual.

Comment: @sp00kyb00g13 See also [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lisp-Data-Types.html#Lisp-Data-Types) and [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lists.html#Lists) from the Elisp manual. These last four links are in case you are not yet particularly familiar with cons cells and lists.